# Como comparar elementos de dos arrays JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Tengo unos checkbox que me permiten filtrar items segun los que esten seleccionados, pero el sistema que estoy fue diseñado para un select de 1 solo valor, ahora lo estoy adaptando para que funcione con arrays en lugar de un numero.

Code

```
let items = this.backup.filter(p => (
          p.tags == tags
          ));
```

Este codigo lo que hace es filtrar los items cuyo array `p.tags` es igual a tags, este funciona pero solo cuando selecciono un solo tag, porque cuando selecciono mas de uno logicamente no sera igual y por eso no funcionara.

Imaginemos que el array `p.tags` tiene este contenido

```
p.tags = ["PHP", "Wordpress"]
```

Y el array tags el siguiente contenido

```
tags = ["Wordpress", "PHP"]
```

Ya con el simple hecho de que esten desordenados ya no son iguales y por lo tanto esto no funciona.

En resumen necesitaria algo que me permita igualarlo a los arrays que sean "Parecidos" y no "Iguales", basandose no en la igualdad entre los arrays sino entre sus contenidos. No se si me explico bien.

Comment: Quieres compara que el contenido de los dos arreglos sea igual, no importa que estén ordenados de distinta manera, no?

Comment: Exactamente @AlejandroMontilla

Comment: Los elementos se pueden repetir o no? Los puedes ordenar?

Comment: No, solamente habra un tag por categoria no se repetiran los nombres de los tags, y cada item tiene los tags que sean pero no debe importar su orden

Answer (score 2):

Seguro hay alguna forma más elegante de hacerlo, pero ordenando ambos arreglos y luego ***comparando*** cada elemento se puede obtener el resultado.

Esta comparación de elementos se puede hacer:

1. Utilizando la función `every`, que itera sobre cada elemento del arreglo.
2. En cada **iteración**, a la función `every` se le pasa una función que tome el elemento y el indice de ese elemento,
   y que compare el elemento contra el elemento del otro arreglo en su la misma posición.
3. Además se debe comparar que los arreglos tengan la misma cantidad de elementos (con `length`).

Ejemplo:

```
array1 = ["uno", "dos", "tres"];    
array2 = ["tres", "dos", "uno"];

//Se ordenan ambos arreglos
array1.sort();
array2.sort();

// y se realiza la comparación de cada elemento
array1.length==array2.length && array1.every(function(v,i) { return v === array2[i] } );
```

Comment: Claro, encontre que el problema es que estoy trayendo los tags de la db con group_concat y una coma para separarlos entonces vienen como tag1, tag2 y yo lo q hago es usar array push para convertirlos en array ahi mismo pero como lo que tengo que hacer es filtrar filter(p.tags = array de tags seleccionados) p.tags ya deberia ser un array, solucionare eso e intentare tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dices es una comparacion,
aqui un ejemplo a la rapida.

```
var encuentra = false;
for(var i =0; i < p.tags.length;i++){
    encuentra = false;
    for(var j =0; j < tags.length;j++){
         if(p.tags[i] == tags[j]){
             encuentra = true;
             break;
         }
    }
    if(!encuenta){
       alert("los arreglos no son iguales");
       break;
    }
}
if(encuentra){
    alert("si son iguales");
}
```

Comment: Se me habia ocurrido usar un for, pero no logre colocarlo dentro de el callback que puse en mi pregunta, me podrias decir como hacerlo?

Comment: Necesito que este dentro de el para usar la variable p.tags

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar el Array.includes(), de esta manera podras revisar si el array dado contiene cada uno de los elementos del segundo array por el cual iteras con la funcion filter, si includes === true puedes crear un nuevo array solo con los elementos retornados por la funcion.

```js
//p.tags = ["PHP", "Wordpress"]
var tags = ["Wordpress", "PHP"]
var items = tags.filter( function (tag) {
  console.log( tags.includes(tag) )
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen diferentes maneras de hacerlo, puede ser que en tu caso baste con asegurarse de que todos los elementos de un array existan en el otro.

```
let items = this.backup.filter(p => (
    //Sí la longitud no es la misma son diferentes
    p.tags.length === tags.length && p.tags.every( item => tags.includes(item) )
));
```

Comment: No Julian, porque no va en la longitud de el array sino en el contenido, yo necesito ese contenido para filtrar las categorias de los items, osea esos nombres dentro del array los necesito, no puedo solo usar el lenght para verificar si son iguales o no.

Comment: Porque suponte que podria ser ["PHP", "ReactJS"] y tendria la misma longitud que ["Wordpress", "PHP"], y el filtrado quedaria cualquier cosa.

Comment: La función no solo usa el length, en realidad compara es el contenido. simplemente que si tienes dos arrays [1, 2, 3] y [1, 2], por la diferencia de longitud ya son diferentes. p.tags.every( item => tags.includes(item) se asegura de que cada elemento en un array exista en el otro

Comment: Mhm, buen punto, pero de todas formas lo probe y no funciona

Comment: creo que sería útil un ejemplo de tu código para poderlo ejecutar y ayudarte  a resolver tu duda. Algo que contenga un ejemplo de this.backup

Comment: Si que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [ "php", "java" ]

const arr1 = [ "php", "java", "mysql" ];
const arr2 = [ "java", "mongodb" ];
const arr3 = [ "ruby" ];
const arr4 = [ "atom", "mega", "php", "java" ];

const arr_ = [ arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 ];

const matches = arr_.filter( array => {
    let posibles = (arr.length * -1); 
    // Si el tamaño es 2, tendremos -2. Al final acabará en 0.

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){

            if(arr[j] == array[i]){
                posibles++;
            }
            
        }

    }
    return posibles ? false : true;
});

console.log(matches); // [ Array(3), Array(4)]
```

De esta manera, se preocupará menos por la longitud.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayContiene(array, elemento) {
 // Si necesitas comprobar un elemento si se encuentra en un arreglo
  array = ["Peras", "Bananas", "Piñas"];
  elemento = "Piñas";
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     if (array[i] === elemento) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  if (array[i] !== elemento) {
    return false;
  }
}
arrayContiene();
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opcion es usar JSON.stringify():

```
JSON.stringify(employee) === JSON.stringify(api.employee)
```