# Como saber si un array tiene elementos repetidos

Tags: javascript, array

Buen día a todos, tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un array como el siguiente:

```
["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]
```

estoy buscando algún método o la manera en la que podría saber si un elemento se repite en mi array, desearía un resultado algo masomenos como esto:

```
["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]//devuelve true
["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]//devuelve false
```

estaba leyendo acerca de los métodos `every()` y `some()`, pero no le veo manera de que me puedan servir.
¿alguien tiene una idea de cómo hacerlo? lo primero que se me ocurre es recorrer el array de manera anidada, para que compare si hay elementos repetidos, pero se me hace muy rebuscado. de todas formas planteo mi idea aquí:

```js
    var array=["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]//devuelve true
    //["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]//devuelve false
    
    var repetido = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) { //revisamos que i sea diferente de j, para que no compare el mismo elemento exacto.
                repetido= true;
             }
         }
     }
     console.log(repetido);
```

Comment: Hola, estos datos lo agregas de algún modo , de ser así se puede validar en ese momento con la función "includes"

Comment: Array ordenados? desordenados? los podes ordenar? y siento decirte, que lo que a vos te parece rebuscado, es lo que hay que hacer, porque es lo que hacen todas esas funciones por debajo ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se puede usar una técnica similar a la propuesta en [esta respuesta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/1264820) a la pregunta de cómo obtener los valores únicos de un array.

La siguiente función

```
function esPrimero(valor, indice, lista) {
    return (lista.indexOf(valor) === indice);
}
```

te dirá si el elemento `valor`, que ocupa el lugar `indice` dentro de la `lista` dada, es la primera vez que aparece en esa lista. El truco se basa en que `lista.indexOf(valor)` te retorna el índice de la primera aparición del valor. Si coincide con el parámetro `indice`, es que es la primera vez que aparece. Si no, es que estamos ante una segunda, tercera, etc.

Análogamente puedes definir su contraria:

```
function noEsPrimero(valor, indice, lista) {
    return !(lista.indexOf(valor) === indice);
}
```

Teniendo estas funciones, es fácil hacer lo que quieres. La lista no tiene elementos repetidos siempre que TODOS ellos (every) sea la primera vez que aparecen. Por tanto: `lista.every(esPrimero)` dará `true` en este caso, y `false` si tiene elementos repetidos.

Si quieres la condición contraria, la lista tendrá elementos repetidos siempre que ALGUNO de ellos (some) no sea la primera vez que aparece. Por tantoo `lista.some(noEsPrimero)` dará `true` en este caso y `false` si todos los elementos son diferentes.

### Demo

```js
function esPrimero(valor, indice, lista) {
    return (lista.indexOf(valor) === indice);
}

function noEsPrimero(valor, indice, lista) {
    return !(lista.indexOf(valor) === indice);
}

l1 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]  // tiene repetidos
l2 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]  // no tiene repetidos

console.log("l1 tiene repetidos?", l1.some(noEsPrimero));
console.log("l2 tiene repetidos?", l2.some(noEsPrimero));
console.log("l1 todos diferentes?", l1.every(esPrimero));
console.log("l2 todos diferentes?", l2.every(esPrimero));
```

Answer (score 7):

Se puede hacer usando `new Set(array)`, esto hace un nuevo *Set* de elementos (juego de elementos), que no están repetidos.

Se obtiene la cantidad de elementos del *set* mediante `size`. El `size` siempre será menor o igual que la cantidad original del array, entonces, para saber **si no tiene** repetidos, se puede comparar que `new Set(array)` es igual que `array.length`, pero si se quiere saber **si tiene** repetidos, se comprueba que es diferente, de la siguiente manera.

Fuente: [Un comentario en el chat de SOes (de Pablo Lozano y lois6b)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=48096272#48096272)

Código:

```js
var array_1 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]
var array_2 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]

function tiene_repetidos(array){
  return new Set(array).size!==array.length
}

console.log(tiene_repetidos(array_1)) //devuelve true
console.log(tiene_repetidos(array_2)) //devuelve false
```

Comment: De las respuestas, creo que es la mas rápida sin modificar el array original.

Answer (score 6):

Se puede hacer de manera muy simple con una función que verifique si algún elemento del array se repite en el resto de este, preguntando desde la posición subsiguiente (posición+1) de cada elemento en adelante.

Para eso se puede usar la funcion `some()` que verifica si algún elemento del array cumple una condición y la función `indexOf()` que indica si un valor existe en un array desde una posición en adelante, quedando el código de la siguiente forma:

```js
var myArr1 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"];//devuelve true
var myArr2 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"];//devuelve false

//esta funcion indica si el array tiene repetidos
function repetidos(arr){
  return arr.some(function(v,i) { return arr.indexOf(v,i+1)>-1 })
}

console.log(repetidos(myArr1)); 
console.log(repetidos(myArr2));
```

Considero que esta es una forma mas simplificada y precisa que mi respuesta anterior original.

**Respuesta Anterior**

Para hacerlo puedes primero usar una función para eliminar los elementos repetidos y luego comparas este nuevo array con el orignal:

```js
var myArr1 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"];//devuelve true
var myArr2 = ["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"];//devuelve false

//con esta funcion eliminas los repetidos
Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
  return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a,b+1)<0
});

//con esta comparas si se repite un elemento
function repetidos(arr){
  if(arr.unique().every(function(v,i) { return v === arr[i] } ))
    return false;
  else 
    return true;
}

console.log( repetidos(myArr1)); 
console.log( repetidos(myArr2));
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La función que has usado es correcta, pero optimizable:

```js
var array=["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]//devuelve true
    //["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]//devuelve false
    
    var repetido = false;
    // El primer bucle compara con el segundo, así que no hace falta llegar al último valor (... < array.length-1).
    for (var i = 0; !repetido && i < array.length-1; i++) {
        // El segundo bucle puede empezar a continuación del primero,
        // ya que los anteriores ya se comprovaron (j=i+1)
        for (var j = i+1; !repetido && j < array.length; j++) {
            // El resultado de la comparación indica si es repetido.
            // En caso que sea true, no hace falta buscar mas,
            // así que saldrá de los dos bucles (!repetido&&...)
            repetido = array[i] == array[j];
         }
     }
     console.log(repetido);
```

Una variación que podría ser más optima (bajando un nivel de ejecución) seria usar el método `indexOf()` para buscar el valor dentro del resto del array usando el método `splice()`.

```js
var array=["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"]//devuelve true
// var array=["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI28"]//devuelve false
    
    var repetido = false;
    for (var i = 0; !repetido && i < array.length-1; i++) {
          repetido = array.slice(i+1).indexOf(array[i])!=-1;
     }
     console.log(repetido);
```

NOTA: De todas maneras, sigue siendo una solución lenta, la mas rápida sin que modifique el array original, es la que te proporciona @user13558

Answer (score 1):

Recientemente publiqué una respuesta pero me la han borrado. No sé por qué. Bueno, hablando de averiguar elementos repetidos de un array es tan sencillo como ordenar el array y determinar si el siguiente y el precedente son iguales. La operación la realizamos con un bucle "for".

Pongo una página completa para verlo. Este es el código:

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Pagina nueva 1</title>
</head>

<script language=javascript>

 //Creamos el array en la forma que lo expone el forero.

conjunto=new Array("FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29")



function calcularrepeticion(){
//ordenamos la array, y cómo sólo hay elementos alfanuméricos pues no es necesario recurrir a una función auxiliar

conjunto.sort();

//generamos un bucle y un condicional que determine si hay repetición

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
if(conjunto[i]==conjunto[i-1]){resultado.innerHTML="el elemento del array que se repite es: "+conjunto[i]}

/*
Dado que se ordenaron todos los elementos, se supone que hay dos "FI29"
consecutivos. El bucle detecta que existe un elemento en el puesto "i" y otro
inmediatamente anterior "i-1" que son iguales. Entonces devuelve true al 
valor "conjunto[i]" y aparece en pantalla sustituyendo al identificador  "resultado" de body
*/


}

</script>

<body onload="calcularrepeticion()">

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><b><font face="Arial" size="4" id=resultado>.</font></b></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma un poco más práctica de poder lograr esto, es usar el constructor [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) para agrupar los valores únicos, de esta manera puedes comprobar fácilmente si ambas matrices (arrays) tienen los mismos valores, en ese caso, el *array* no tendrá elementos repetidos.

> Los objetos Set son colecciones de valores. Puede iterar a través de los elementos de un conjunto en orden de inserción. Un valor en un Set solo puede ocurrir una vez; es único en la colección del Set.
>
> - Extraído de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const MyArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "aa", "dd", "d"];

function HasRepeatedEls(Arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(Arr)) {
    throw new Error("El dato recibido no es un array");
  }
  const UniqueArray = [...new Set(Arr)];
  return JSON.stringify(Arr.sort()) !== JSON.stringify(UniqueArray.sort());
  // También podrías lograrlo con:
  // return Arr.sort().join(",") === UniqueArray.sort().join(",")
  // O incluso:
  // return arr.length !== uniqueSet.size || !arr.every(element => uniqueSet.has(element));
  // Advertencia: Llamar este método en un array vacío devuelve true para cualquier condición (Extraido de MDN)
}

console.log(HasRepeatedEls(MyArray)); // true
```

En el ejemplo anterior, se usa un constructor [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) para generar un listado únicamente de los elementos que no se repiten dentro del array recibido. Y luego, se usa [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) para convertir los dos *arrays* a un string que sea comparable.

**Comentarios adicionales**

- La función `HasRepeatedEls()` devolverá `false` si ambos *arrays* (el que tiene los elementos únicos y el origianl) son iguales.
- Para asegurar que la función no tome en cuenta el orden de los datos, se usa el método [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), de esta manera se ordenan los datos y se evita que la función falle si los datos están desordenados.

> El método `sort()` ordena los elementos de un arreglo (*array*) localmente y devuelve el arreglo ordenado. La ordenación no es necesariamente [estable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). El modo de ordenación por defecto responde a la posición del valor del `string` de acuerdo a su valor [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).
>
> - Extraído de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

- Si ambos *arrays* tienen los mismos elementos, significará que no tienen elementos repetidos, en este caso se usa el operador `!==` para que la expresión devuelva `false` cuando los dos *arrays* son iguales, y `true` en el caso contrario.

---

### Limitaciones

Las funciones `JSON.stringify()` y `Array.prototype.sort()` **solo funcionarán con [tipos de datos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitive), por lo que si usas tipos de datos más complejos, como objetos o constructores, necesitarás otro enfoque.**

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [Sintaxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Tipos de datos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
- [Como comparar elementos de dos arrays JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58967/como-comparar-elementos-de-dos-arrays-javascript)
- [Expresiones y operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Hola Estimados dejo mi aporte. Ojala te sirva.

```js
let lista={};
const arr=["FI29","FI09","JM15","FI29"];
arr.forEach((elemento)=>{
    if(!lista[elemento]){
        lista[elemento]=1;
    }else{
        lista[elemento]+=1;
    }
});

const ListaFinal=Object.entries(lista).sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]);
let resultado=ListaFinal[ListaFinal.length-1][1]>1?'Valores Repetido':'No hay Valores repetidos';
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Edgar, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.