# Como eliminar elementos repetidos en un Array

Tags: javascript

Como eliminar elementos repetidos en un Array, soy novato en esto, se puede hacer con for e ir comparando uno por uno pero quisiera saber si hay un método para realizar eso:

miFuncion("x", 10, 2, "10", 10, true, true]) devolverá ["x", 10, 2, "10", true]) esto quiero hacer[image: Esto es lo que tengo]
[![Esto es lo que tengo][2]][2]

Comment: te puede servir esta pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282378/como-saber-si-un-array-tiene-elementos-repetidos

Comment: Te dejo este par de artículos que te pueden servir: [4 formas de eliminar duplicados en JS](https://matiashernandez.dev/4-formas-de-eliminar-elementos-duplicados-en-un-arreglo-con-javascript) y [Cómo eliminar duplicados en JS](https://www.neoguias.com/como-eliminar-duplicados-array-javascript/#:~:text=Usa%20el%20m%C3%A9todo%20filter,-El%20m%C3%A9todo%20filter&text=El%20m%C3%A9todo%20filter%20est%C3%A1%20disponible,De%20lo%20contrario%20se%20descartar%C3%A1.)

Comment: Mcuchas gracias me sirvieron

Comment: @EdwinEspinal la mejor solución es con el Set(), en los enlaces te aparecen 4 soluciones pero la que está hecha específicamente para evitar elementos repetidos es Set(), el cual puedes trabajar como un array cualquiera.

Si tú eres el que controla la inserción de los datos, reemplaza de una vez el array por el Set()